# Pandas - count sequence of value in each id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, sequence

I would like to count the number of occurrence of sequence of value in column Act for each Id.

dataframe:

```
a = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
    'Act': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B']}
```

The output would be counted the sequence for each different id:

Seq | Count

A  -  A     |   1

A  -  B     |   2

B  -  B     |   1

B  -  A     |   2

Comment: Not sure if I am missing anything here but why is A-B = 1, I see it occurring thrice ?

Comment: please explain a little bit clear ,  i.e what id represents in array  and is that related somehow to the result ??? just explain more about what you want please ...

Comment: A-B represented twice , .... @ManishSaraswat is right ??

Comment: The reason is because A-B only happen once in id 1, there no sequence of A-B happen in id 2. I am sorry. There is mistake in the question, the count for occurrence of sequence A-B should be 2 not 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shift` with `groupby` to create successors for each **id** and hence create a column representing sequences. Then, you can simply employ `pd.value_counts` within groups to count the number of sequences, as follows:

#### Create data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                   'Act': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B']})

print(df)

    Act id
0   A   1
1   B   1
2   A   1
3   A   1
4   B   2
5   B   2
6   A   2
7   B   2
```

#### Sequence counts within groups

```
# shift `Act` within id groups to get successor
df["Act Shifted"] = df.groupby("id").shift(-1)

# concatenate predeccesor and successor to get sequence column
df["Seq"] = df["Act"].str.cat(df["Act Shifted"], " - ")

print(df)

    Act id  Act Shifted Seq
0   A   1   B           A - B
1   B   1   A           B - A
2   A   1   A           A - A
3   A   1   NaN         NaN
4   B   2   B           B - B
5   B   2   A           B - A
6   A   2   B           A - B
7   B   2   NaN         NaN
```

Now simply count within groups:

```
# group by id and count sequences
df.groupby("id")["Seq"].apply(pd.value_counts)


id       
1   A - A    1
    A - B    1
    B - A    1
2   B - B    1
    A - B    1
    B - A    1
Name: Seq, dtype: int64
```

#### Overall sequence counts

If you want to get sequence counts irrespective of id, remove the `groupby`:

```
df["Seq"].value_counts()
A - B    2
B - A    2
B - B    1
A - A    1
Name: Seq, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. its really help.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.Series(list(zip(a['Act'], a['Act'][1:]))).value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
                   'Act': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B']})

df['Act'].str.cat(df.groupby('id').shift(-1)['Act'], ' - ').value_counts().sort_index()
```

Result:

```
A - A    1
A - B    2
B - A    2
B - B    1
Name: Act, dtype: int64
```